# How I can to create PCL5 function to print bitmap?

Tags: windows, mobile, printer-control-language

I have a HP officejet H470 and it has a Bluetooth device to connect with other devices such as handheld.

I want to print a bitmap image By PLC5, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to find the specification of the protocol.

Presumably [AirPrint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPrint).

Comment: NO,I have not an experience in this topic . All things I want to print the image in printer without using the printer driver but print by open the serial port and write the print command language to printer directly.